# Download all .gz files from a website with http

Tags: wget, http

I have tried the following:

```
 wget -nd -r -l1 -A gz http://www.example.com/products
```

This only saved a `.txt` file where it says:

> ```
> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /
> ```

On the other hand

```
 wget -r http://www.example.com/products/*.gz
```

simply does not work.

What are some other commands I should try?

Comment: The only acceptable solution is one that the website owner would agree to, which is why you should contact them if your request is legitimate.

Comment: @JuliePelletier using wget to download one .gz file is fine so I assumed batch downloading should work too

Comment: The server is probably refusing to give you a directory listing.

Comment: In addition to what @JuliePelletier said, HTTP doesn't even really *have* the concept of a directory listing, not like FTP (or Gopher or other older protocols) does. The fact that http://something/foo/ *might* return an HTML page containing a list or files in the "foo" directory is only a convention.

Answer (score 1):

Your first command does not look bad, but like others already wanted to say: the website owner placed a robots.txt which wants any search engine – or similar web spider programs, which includes wget – to stay off her site (be it to prevent unnecessary traffic or because of any other reason). wget does respect this by default, see the wget manual (e.g. `info wget`) section 9.1 (in Chapter 9: Appendices) for finding the tunable robot related features for your .wgetrc (also settable via `-e …` command line option).